# React Admin - Pagination not working (Uncaught TypeError: i is not a function)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-admin

I'm working on a website with React admin but for some reason the pagination doesn't work. If I click on the next button or on a number it throws an `"Uncaught TypeError: i is not a function"` error in the console.

[the error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/borEd.png)

It seems to be an error in the Pagination Actions file. [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cnadY.png)

But, when I shrink the windows size until a new type of the pagination buttons is displayed, clicking on it works and changes the page [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5c8zH.png)

Comment: Can you create a working example reproducing the error using https://codesandbox.io/ or similar? It'd be easier for us to help you that way